# How I can access to couchbase from pyspark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, couchbase

I'm new in working with **NoSQL** databases. I have **Spark 1.6.0** on my cluster and I need to get document from **Couchbase** bucket, make some operations with it an load it back. 
I know **ip**, **port**, bucket's **name** and bucket's **password**. Unfortunately, I'm out of ideas, how I can access this database using **pyspark**. But if it's impossible, how I can do it using **scala**? 
Besides, I need execute suchlike operation with **HBase**. 

Great thanks for any suggestions and useful urls.


Best regards,
Vladimir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access Couchbase from the Python tools universe, you need to use the Python SDK.

Start here: https://docs.couchbase.com/python-sdk/2.5/start-using-sdk.html